# Unable to get value from Dynamic Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have used below code to get value from textarea and I am not able to get it.
Given is the code for the textarea which is dynamic:

```
 <form name="myForm">
 <textarea name="fname" <%#!((GPNS.BusinessLayer.SpecialItems.SpecialItem)Container.DataItem).Code.Equals("OTH", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ? "style='display: none;'" : string.Empty%> id="text<%#((GPNS.BusinessLayer.SpecialItems.SpecialItem)Container.DataItem).ID%>" maxlength="50" placeholder="Enter other item details"></textarea>
 </form>
```

Given is my function to get value from textarea box:

```
 function ValidateData() {
            if ($("textarea").is(":visible")) {
                //var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
                var x = document.getElementsByName("fname").value;
                if (x == null || x == "") {
                    alert("Please Enter Other Item Details");
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else return true
        }
```

Comment: Check if the name of the textarea is same as you are using in the code. Right click>Inspect Element> Go to your textarea and check the name.

Comment: yes it is same as describe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for get `textarea`:

```
function ValidateData() {
        if ($("textarea").is(":visible")) {
            var x = $("textarea").val();
            if (x == null || x == "") {
                alert("Please Enter Other Item Details");
                return false;
            }
        }
        else return true
    }
```

Comment: Still Not able to get value, whatever i input it gives me null value.